# Can the striker be dismissed, Caught, if the ball is deflected off an umpire?

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

Can the striker be dismissed, Caught, if the ball is deflected off an umpire before that fielder takes the catch?

Comment: Is it "the ball is deflected off an umpire **after** that fielder takes the catch" or "the ball is deflected off an umpire **before** that fielder takes the catch"?

Comment: It is the ball is deflected off an umpire before that fielder takes the catch and here fielder takes the catch in the second attempt.in the first attempt the ball is deflected by fielder.

Comment: @SportsFan - So this website is now started generating duplicate posts regularly. :-)

Answer (score 4):

[Law 32 of the Laws of cricket here](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-32-caught-1/)

> #### fair catch
>
> (d) a fielder catches the ball after it has touched an umpire, another fielder or the other batsman.

Comment: i think this scenario is if the ball hits directly to the umpire before fielder takes the catch.

Comment: You have asked for the same @KeerthiKumar. Please update your question with the latest scenario.